# pgf plot stacked bar graph random colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I created this graph, but the colors are repeating since there are a lot of them.
Is there a way to randomly generate colors for the bars?
Here's the overleaf doc: https://www.overleaf.com/read/pbkypqcqppbj
Thanks!
[image]

Edit: in response to the comments, the reason why I want to have so many classes is to visualize a certain dataset, and there is previous work showing in the same way, so I'm trying to do the same [image]

Comment: This is not going to help you with coding but is this the best way to show your data? Having so many classes does not make for an understandable graphic. I would rethink the way to reprent the data first.

Comment: I wanted to write exactly the same like @Peter Jansson. If you have a good reason to do it that way, please confirm and provide the reason. There might be a better over all approach.

Comment: I edited the question. I need to have this many colors ("classes") because I'm trying to do the same thing as a previous paper did for visualizing dataset.

Comment: Random colors would imply the possibility of duplicates (as opposed to a random sort).  In any case, what you really want is to create a new `bar cycle list` (page 55-56).